# Mysql database design: table with half a million rows

Tags: mysql, database-design

I realize that there are similar questions answered on this site but I could not get the solution for me from those questions. For example, I have 10.000 posts in the website and each of those posts has 50 reviews. Should I create

1.One table with 500.000 rows (reviews)

or

2 .10.000 tables (each post has its own table for reviews (50 rows))
Could you help me to understand please.

Comment: One table. Dont create tables during runtime. You create the tables and dont change them later. And 500k rows is nothing. You can look up the wordpress table design for inspiration

Comment: Thank you very much! I have also another problem. Each of those posts has "vote up" button. So if I have 10.000 users, potentially each of the posts can be voted 10.000 times. Hence, if I keep all the post_id-user_id combinations in one table, the number of rows can reach up to 100.000.000. How can I design database in this case? Should I create seperate table for each user where I will be able to save ids of the posts for which the user voted?

Comment: No, stop thinking about using seperate tables. A DB can handle billions of records. Use indexes to speed things. And if it really gets slow someday you can start thinking about partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's not a good idea to create tables during runtime, so you should create one table in this case
2. Reviews table - 500.000 rows is ok
3. Vote Up table - Actually, the number of rows will not reach to 100.000.000 because it's impossible that each post will be voted by all the users, so you can create one table in this case as well

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a table named POST and a table named REVIEW. Each post has an ID (primary key of the table POST) that you can use as foreign key in the table REVIEW to index all reviews relative to a post. And as Tim Castelijns just said, 500k row are nothing for a normal DB and its performances are not really going affected by this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have also another problem. Each of those posts has "vote up" button. So if I have 10.000 users, potentially each of the posts can be voted 10.000 times. Hence, if I keep all the post_id-user_id combinations in one table, the number of rows can reach up to 100.000.000. How can I design database in this case? Should I create seperate table for each user where I will be able to save ids of the posts for which the user voted?

Comment: In general, create tables at runtime is a wrong idea, and you're going to do so if you create separate table for each user. I'd simply create a table VOTEUP with the ID of the post and the ID of the user that voted up. If needed, you can also create an attribute in the POST table to store the number of votes up of a post (to display it, I guess).

Comment: Yes, that is what I described in my comment. The problem is that the number of rows of such table can reach up to 100.000.000. Is it normal?